# Class 4 SDHC vs Class 10 SDHC cards

Tags: linux, sd-card

I have been working on some programs that require data to be written/stored onto the SDHC cards, few MBs in size, Sandisk class 4 SDHC * Sandisk class 10 SDHC 16 GB cards in particular.

The results I have observed seems more strange. The write speeds of class 4 cards vs class 10 cards.

Commands used:

I have used dd command to write the data; something like:

> dd if=file_10mb.img of=/dev/sdc conv=fsync bs=4096 count=2560

Measured the write speeds by:

> iostat /dev/sdc 1 -m -t

Few figures:

**Writing a 100MB file:**

> On class 10 card: 53 secs ->Avg. write speed = 2.03 MB_wrtn/sec
>
> On class 4 card: 31 secs ->Avg. write speed = 2.62 MB_wrtn/sec

**Writing a 10MB file:**

> On class 10 card: 5.7 secs ->Max. & Min. write speed = 1.85 & 1.15
> MB_wrtn/sec
>
> On class 4 card: 4 secs ->Max. & Min. write speed = 2.56 & 1.15
> MB_wrtn/sec

I expected these results to be exactly opposite as class 10 cards should outperform class 4 cards.

I've tested these on two different cards to remove the probability of wrong readings due to aged cards. Also, the cards are fairly new.

Please let me know about the strange behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you write the data? In command line with `cp`, or from a program you wrote? Post some code (this site is about programming).

Comment: I have used dd command to write the data; something like:

dd if=file_10mb.img of=/dev/sdc conv=fsync bs=4096 count=2560

Comment: bs=4096 is way too small in general, and is almost criminal used along with conv=fsync. Use bigger blocks (say, 4 MB) and a single sync at the end.

Comment: @matteo italia .. While I shall follow your suggestion and get back to the readings, can you plz explain why is it a major issue when conv=fsync is used. I expect the entire data to be written and not just stay in the driver buffers, etc. And how is fsync different from sync command. It will even help if you could please point to any links

Comment: The point is that it forces a sync at each write, and given that your writes are quite small (4 KB) your bottleneck most probably is not the actual device sustained throughput, but the latency of all those forced syncs. Doing a single sync at the end makes sure that the OS and driver buffers do their own thing and keep feeding the device as fast as it allows while you are writing, but still making sure that you are measuring the time needed to actually write all the data.

Comment: I was able to probe into the issue and was able to see "mmcqd" behave differently when class 4 and class 10 cards are used. As I used class 4 cards, the kthread was getting CPU time almost very often. But in case of class 10, the same was taking more time than usual. Hence the disk IO writes were slower. Yet to figure out the actual cause. Thanks for the inputs @Matteo Italia

Answer (score 2):

A brief research on internet lead me to this page: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11258&p=123670

which talks about "erase blocks", the size of an "erase" operation; this erase block is generally bigger than a sector size, which is the minimum size for a write operation.  On that page some example is shown:

> 16 GB SanDisk Extreme Pro: erase block size of 4 MB.
>   8 GB Transcend SDHC 150x: erase block size of 4 MB.
>   2 GB Transcend SD 150x: erase block size of 8 kB.

Now, your `fsync` options passed to dd means that after every write, a sync is performed on both the data *and* metadata, which could involve rewriting part of the FAT, or some other blocks if no FAT is used.

On a classic spinning magnetic disk, that would mean that the head travels a lot, every 4Kb; on a flash memory there is no head, but an erase operation is very costly. Moreover, flash memories have internal algorithms that reduce the wearing, so it becomes very difficult to know what really goes on underneath, inside the memory card.

The conclusion is that, as noted in a comment, 4K block size can be too small, and the fsync option slows down and can be *very* problematic. Get rid of fsync options, and perform again tests with different block sizes.

In reality, probably every different card has a preferred set of parameters. One way class 10 cards can work faster, can be to choose a big erase block. The time for erasing a block is more or less independent of its size, so a really big erase block effectively improves speed, by erasing more data in the same time. But if blocks are erased too often, speed is reduced instead.

The final answer, from inference, is that your set of parameters seem better suited for a class 4 card than for a class 10 card. In my opinion, your parameters are *not* well suited for anything, but nobody can be perfectly sure: flash memory cards are intricated. For example, often I record TV transmissions on my TV decoder; there are periods of time in which things go smoothly, and other periods not. 4 months ago the decoder was often complaining about "slow writing speed", with horrible results. Since a couple of months, everything is fine. I touched nothing, the flash USB memory is the same. Probably it entered another phase of its life...